# Selecting names with two consecutive, same letters

Tags: c#, strings, linq

I've a list of names that I'd like to iterate over and extract from it those names that have two letters that are the same right next to each other (i.e. Bill, Terry, Debby, Aaron, etc.).

The below code I have accomplishes this task, however I was wondering if there was a more efficient or line-friendly method of approaching this problem.

I started thinking about a solution involving LINQ's `Where<>` method, but then I wasn't sure how to use both a `string` variable and an `int` index variable inside a lambda expression.

Also, does there exist a way to accomplish this task in faster than `O(n^2)` time?

```
public static List<string> DoubleLetters(string[] array)
{
    List<string> doubleLetter = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].Length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (char.ToLower(array[i][j]) == char.ToLower(array[i][j + 1]))
            {
                doubleLetter.Add(array[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return doubleLetter;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The outer `for` loop can be replaced with a `foreach` loop: `foreach (var name in names)`. It removes the need for two counter variables, and simplifies indexing of the array, making the code easier to read.
- This method would be more flexible if it accepted a single string and returned a boolean: `bool HasRepeatingLetters(string str)`. That allows you to use it for single names as well as for multiple names.
- For multiple names, the above method can easily be combined with Linq: `var matchingNames = names.Where(name => HasRepeatingLetters(name)).ToArray()` (you can remove the `ToArray` (or `ToList`) call if you want lazy evaluation). In this case, you don't even need an anonymous function, because the signature of `HasRepeatingLetters` already matches what `Where` requires: `names.Where(HasRepeatingLetters)`.
- Keep in mind that `ToLower` is culture-dependent (not all languages use the same upper/lowercase conversion rules). You may want to give your function an extra (optional) `CultureInfo` argument to control its behavior.
- Performance of your function should be `O(n)`, not `O(n^2)`. Passing in twice as many strings, or strings that are twice as long, requires twice as much work, not four times as much. It would only be `O(n^2)` if, for example, you compared each string against every other string.
- Calling `ToLower` on the given string would simplify your code, and it should be a bit faster too for names without repeating characters. You could also keep your `for` loop, but store the previous lower-cased character as you go, so you don't need to convert it to lower-case twice. That would make the code a little more complicated, so it's probably not worth the hassle. Of course, if performance is important, you should actually measure it.

Comment: ToLower can have problems with Turkish letters.  Would be better to use ToUpper.

Comment: @RickDavin: if you're working with Turkish names you should use a Turkish `CultureInfo`, otherwise both `ToLower` and `ToUpper` are going to give incorrect results (but for different characters).

Comment: The problem is that "ii" in Turkish are surrogate pairs and treated as one character.  Converting to "II" is safer route.

Comment: @RickDavin: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you provide an example where `ToLower` fails but `ToUpper` works?

Comment: foreach is slower than for

Comment: @Paparazzi: in this case the OP is accessing `array[i]` multiple times, so the `for` loop turns out to be slower. If I store `array[i]` in a local variable then I'm seeing `for` and `foreach` perform equally well. In theory, `foreach` should be slower, but I suspect the JITter is just doing a good job here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a LINQ version using Zip.

Enumerate over each character in a word and compares adjacent characters by offsetting, one enumeration, by one character, using 'Skip(1)'.
Pair characters with 'Zip'.
A match on 'Any' pair confirms.

```
var doubleLetters =
    array
    .Where(word => word.Zip(
                       word.Skip(1),
                       (ch1, ch2) => char.ToUpper(ch1) == char.ToUpper(ch2))
                   .Any(
                       match => match))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `ToCharArray()` is not necessary. A string is already a char-array.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution to my question through the use of lovely, lovely regular expressions (and LINQ, conveniently enough)!

I was able to extract the names `Terry`, `Bill`, `Aaron`, and `Debby` using the below line of code:

```
string[] newArray = array.Where(x => new Regex(@"((?i)[a-z\d])\1").IsMatch(x)).ToArray();
```

...where

- `(?i)` - Ignore case of letter in the name
- `(a-z\d)` - Look for any letter of the alphabet
- `\1` - Repeat search of `(a-z\d)` group

Still not too sure about time complexity, though. Regex time complexity eludes me :-P

Comment: Using of `Regex` is a good solution, but: **1)** use `\w` instead of `[a-z\d]` since `\w` includes digits too and works for non-English letters; **2)** move creation of `Regex` out of the `Where`, there is no need to create the same object multiple times. And finally: **your regex doesn't work**. I've checked it for `"Aaron"` and `IsMatch` returned `false`. The correct regular expression is `new Regex(@"(\w)\1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`.

Comment: Hmm...I thought you could use `(?i)` instead of `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` for case-insensitivity.

Comment: Doesn't seem that I'm using `(?i)` correctly. I suppose I was too eager to answer my own question :-P

Comment: You can but you need to place `(?i)` at the start of regex pattern in your case. `new Regex(@"(?i)(\w)\1")` will work. But I prefer to use `RegexOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

For a while I thought you code was broken but I had a bad test

I think this would work but not much different than your
I only wrote it because I thought your was broken

```
public static List<string> DoubleLetters2(string[] array)
{
    List<string> doubleLetter = new List<string>();
    foreach(string s in array)
    {
        if (DoubleLettersHelper(s))
        {
            doubleLetter.Add(s);
        }
    }
    return doubleLetter;
}
public static bool DoubleLettersHelper(string array)
{
    string lower = array.ToLower();
    for (int i = 0; i < lower.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (lower[i] == lower[i + 1])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? The OP's code really is only comparing adjacent characters, and doesn't return `"Teryry"` when I test it.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I just tested again and it does not return for me.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet It works.  I had a bad test.